# If the power series$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$converges For $x=3$,Then

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> **Question**If the power series$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$converges
>   For $x=3$,Then
>
> [image]

**Any Hint will be very much useful**

Comment: Hint: RADIUS of convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expanded centred at zero, with radius at least $3$, so it must converge absolutely for $x=-2$. It converges absolutely for $x=1$. It converges for $x=-2$. It converges absolutely for $x=-1$.

Comment: So within the interval of convergence power series converges absolutely. And also at boundary points of interval?

Comment: No, the boundary points are uncertain. But interior points, yes.